# How to use select to properly detect whether I am building C++ code in Windows or Linux?

Tags: c++, bazel

I am writing a sample C++ project that uses Bazel to serve as an example idiom for other collaborators to follow.

Here is the repository: https://github.com/thinlizzy/bazelexample

I am interested to know if I am doing it 'right', more specifically about this file: https://github.com/thinlizzy/bazelexample/blob/38cc07931e58ff5a888dd6a83456970f76d7e5b3/demo/BUILD
 when regarding to pick particular implementations.

```
cc_library(
    name = "demo",
    srcs = ["demo.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "//example:frontend",
    ],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "main_win",
    deps = [
        ":demo",
        "//example:impl_win",
    ],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "main_linux",
    deps = [
        ":demo",
        "//example:impl_linux",
    ],
)
```

Is this following a correct/expected idiom for Bazel projects? I am doing this way already for other projects, by concentrating all the platform-specific dependencies in separate targets and then the binaries just depend on them.

Someone in bazel-discuss list told me to use **select**, instead, but my attempts failed to 'detect' the operating system. I'm sure I did something wrong, but the lack of info and examples don't tell me much how to use it properly.

Comment: Please insert code You want to fix directly here

Comment: as I said in the question, I am worried about this file: https://github.com/thinlizzy/bazelexample/blob/master/demo/BUILD

- how can I use select there to have only one binary target, instead of two?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`@bazel_tools` contains predefined platform conditions:

```
$ bazel query @bazel_tools//src/conditions:all
@bazel_tools//src/conditions:windows_msys
@bazel_tools//src/conditions:windows_msvc
@bazel_tools//src/conditions:windows
@bazel_tools//src/conditions:remote
@bazel_tools//src/conditions:host_windows_msys
@bazel_tools//src/conditions:host_windows_msvc
@bazel_tools//src/conditions:host_windows
@bazel_tools//src/conditions:freebsd
@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin_x86_64
@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin
```

You can use them directly in the `BUILD` file:

```
cc_library(
  name = "impl",
  srcs = ["Implementation.cpp"] + select({
    "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:windows": ["ImplementationWin.cpp"],
    "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": ["ImplementationMacOS.cpp"],
     "//conditions:default": ["ImplementationLinux.cpp"],
  }),
  # .. same for hdrs and data
)

cc_binary(
  name = "demo",
  deps = [":impl"],
)
```

See the documentation for [`select`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/functions.html#select) for details on the syntax.

Comment: This so needs to be documented with `select`!

Comment: How do I use these conditions in plain `if`? I've created a question for this, even: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56065453/637669

Comment: This answer is now outdated. `@platforms` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

@Vertexwahn's answer caused some confusion on my end, so I hope this answer helps clarify a bit. While his answer does not directly tie into the question, it may be of use to others trying to build on entirely different platforms without file specific inclusions.

Here is a link to where I answered that particular question: [How do I specify portable build configurations for different operating systems for Bazel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72031612/how-do-i-specify-portable-build-configurations-for-different-operating-systems-f)

Comment: this is great info! maybe you can extract this comment to a self-answered question in SO and link it to here

Comment: What do you think I should title the question to benefit others in finding this info for this aspect of Bazel? It has been a while since I encountered and resolved this issue. @thinlizzy

Comment: maybe "specifying portable build configurations in .bazelrc" ?

Comment: Note: I deleted my answer